# install a vnc client on windows 7 without admin privileges

Tags: vnc

Is there a open source vnc client on windows 7 that can be installed without admin privileges

I tried TightVNC, UltraVNC, RealVNC, but all require admin priveldges just to install the client (not the server)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about locating and installing general software, and is not a programming question in accordance with the [help] guidelines. In addition, it would be off-topic anyway because it's asking us to find or recommend a tool, library, software, book, tutorial, or favorite off-site resource.

Answer (score 3):

Found it... https://www.realvnc.com/download/get/1611/

Simply a vncviewer standalone

Comment: still not helpful, as the installation still requires admin privileges.

Comment: @thedigitalmouse This just worked for me. I had to choose 'Standalone EXE x64` instead of `EXE x86/x64` in the dropdown menu of @amulllb's link. In the downloaded viewer, choose "File/open connection" instead of "open session" to avoid creating an account on realvnc.com's servers.